# How get out of Ubuntu Recovery Menu?

Tags: boot, data-recovery, recovery-mode

I had a problem in booting my Ubuntu so I followed the steps to boot in recovery mode , but when I reached this recovery menu , it does got any back or forward even if I press enter or press exit , it just isn't working . It's just stuck in that place . And when I pressed ctrl+c now it isn't even moving up and down , it's just stuck . It's not even shutting down by pressing power button.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hold the power button for a force reboot

Comment: Thank you . It  shut down.

Comment: @Ras_0612 since it helped you, can u make my answer as the accepted answer?